# Rails before_save not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, associations

I have an ActiveRecord model 'offer' that belongs to 2 instances of item. Item belongs to user.

The offer model has the following:

offered_item_id
receiving_item_id
offering_user_id
receiving_user_id

In the creation of the model I want Rails to save the users by reading the item ID and going through that relation.

I have got this:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :offered_item_id, :receiving_item_id, :state

    belongs_to :offering_user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :receiving_user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :offered_item, class_name: "Item"
  belongs_to :receiving_item, class_name: "Item"

  before_save :populate_user_ids

  private
        def populate_user_ids
            self.receiving_user_id = self.receiving_item.user.id
            self.offering_user_id = self.offered_item.user.id
        end 

end
```

But even when hard-coding the values in the `populate_user_ids` method doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure `before_save` is even called.

My tests are passing with the item relations but the user relations fail miserably.

See my RSpec tests:

```
describe "relations" do
        it { should respond_to (:offering_user) }
        it { should respond_to (:offered_item) }
        it { should respond_to (:receiving_user) }
        it { should respond_to (:receiving_item) }
        its(:offering_user) { should == offering_user } #FAILS
        its(:offered_item) { should == offered_item }
        its(:receiving_user) { should == receiving_user } #FAILS
        its(:receiving_item) { should == receiving_item }
    end
```

Apologies I'm pretty new to Rails.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You need to let Rails do the work of handling the id's in a `belongs_to` and `has_many`, etc, relationship. Have you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html?

Comment: Yeh I've done that for the items but i don't want the user's to be accessible in a public interface (to avoid mass assignment) so I am trying to set those behind the scenes

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Rails does do it "behind the scenes" and you can control what the user sees in the view. But to your original issue, did you try a `puts` in your `before_save` to see if it's being called? Hard to tell what might be happening not knowing what the controller looks like also.

Comment: Do you get an error when trying to save an offer?

Comment: Nope no error, I am assuming let!(:offer) { offered_item.offers_made_with.build(receiving_item_id: receiving_item.id) } does call save right?

Comment: Where will the output display if I use puts?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I'm a flippin' numpty.

I was using:

```
let!(:offer) { offered_item.offers_made_with.build(receiving_item_id: receiving_item.id) }
```

rather than:

```
let!(:offer) { offered_item.offers_made_with.create(receiving_item_id: receiving_item.id) }
```

`build` doesn't save, `create` does.